# Grab rows between two Datetime and avoid iterating

Tags: python-2.7, date, pandas

I use Pandas to retrieve a lot of Data via an SQL query (from Hive). I have a big DataFrame now:

```
market_pings =  pandas.read_sql_query(query, engine)
market_pings['event_time'] = pandas.to_datetime(market_pings['event_time'])
```

I have calculated `Time Delta` periods which are: if something interesting happens within the timeline of these events within this `market_pings` DataFrame, I want the logs of that time interval only.

To grab DataFrame rows where a column has certain values there is a cool trick:

```
valuelist = ['value1', 'value2', 'value3']
df = df[~df.column.isin(value_list)]
```

Does anyone have an idea how to do this for time periods, so that I get the events of certain times from the market_pings DataFrame without direct Iteration (row by row)? 
I can build a list of periods (1s accuracy) like:

```
2015-08-03 19:19:47 
2015-08-03 19:20:00
```

But this means my `valuelist` becomes a tupel and I somehow have to compare dates.

Comment: Like values in list you wanted time stamp in list am I right? Or something else you are looking?

Comment: Do you want records in your DataFrame that have event times within an interval (after a start time and before an end time) or those that have event times that are inside a given list of times?

Comment: exactly; so in this case I want event time within the interval. 2015-08-03 19:19:47 to 2015-08-03 19:20:00. Not the specific values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a list of time stamp as value_list and do operation you intend to.

```
time_list = [pd.Timestamp('2015-08-03 19:19:47'),pd.Timestamp('2015-08-03 19:20:00') ]
```

One thing in using between_time() is index have to be that date or time,
If not you can set by [set_index()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html)

```
mydf = pd.Series(np.random.randn(4), time_list)

mydf
Out[123]: 
2015-08-03 19:19:47    0.632509
2015-08-03 19:20:00   -0.234267
2015-08-03 19:19:48    0.159056
2015-08-03 21:20:00   -0.842017
dtype: float64

mydf.between_time(start_time=pd.Timestamp('2015-08-03 19:19:47'),
      end_time=pd.Timestamp('2015-08-03 19:20:00'),include_end=False)
Out[124]: 
2015-08-03 19:19:47    0.632509
2015-08-03 19:19:48    0.159056
dtype: float64

mydf.between_time(start_time=pd.Timestamp('2015-08-03 19:19:47'),       
                    end_time=pd.Timestamp('2015-08-03 19:20:00'),
                      include_end=False,include_start=False)
Out[125]: 
2015-08-03 19:19:48    0.159056
dtype: float64
```

Comment: In that case I get 2 events with these exact time stamps. However the events in between get ignored. I can build a time_list and in a loop add the stamps. But that means that I depend on the accuracy a lot and I bloat the time_list in case of large periods.

Comment: @wishi: look into to this, http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.between_time.html. I ll ans in some time